# Improving if-else with multiple values?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

## Is there a better way to do this?

```
if(cpf.length !== 11 || cpf === "00000000000" || cpf === "11111111111" ||
        cpf === "22222222222" || cpf === "33333333333" || cpf === "44444444444" ||
        cpf === "55555555555" || cpf === "66666666666" || cpf === "77777777777" ||
        cpf === "88888888888" || cpf === "99999999999"){
```

Comment: Technically this is more of a "code review" than an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could debate if this is *better* but this is what I like to do in that sort of situation:

```
// Name this something relevant to the problem
var possibleValues = ["0000000000", ...];
if (possibleValues.includes(cpf)) {
  // do stuff
}
```

or if you're in an environment that doesn't have `includes`

```
if (possibleValues.indexOf(cpf) > -1) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Another possibility is using a regular expression:

```
if (cpf.length === 11 && cpf.match(/^(\d)\1+$/)) {
  // do stuff
}
```

- `^`: Start at the beginning
- `(\d)`: Look for a digit and remember it
- `\1+`: Look for the remembered digit repeatedly
- `$`: Hit the end of the string

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sometimes i get 'tunnel vision' when working improvements for things like this. Also is there any performance gain/loss on the solutions above?. I loved the RegEx solution btw!

Comment: @VictorMedeiros Glad I could help! Technically, all of these solutions are likely slower than a bunch of `||`s. However, it's likely a difference of 1ms or less and unless you *really* need to squeeze out that last little drop, it's not worth the effort and cruft to optimize it. Always make sure it works and works *fast enough* before optimizing.

Comment: to be precise, this part shouldn't be `\1{10}` rather than `\1+`, **Edit:** wait something's wrong here his first condition is `cpf.length !== 11` so this whole thing should be `if (cpf.length !== 11 || cpf.test(/^(\d)\1{10}$/)) { ... }`

Comment: sry, realized too late that I have a mistake in my edit: it's `regex.test(value)` or `string.match(regex)` so ... `if (cpf.length !== 11 || cpf.match(/^(\d)\1{10}$/)) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

Using `indexOf` Something like

```
var possibleValues = [ "00000000000", "1111111111" ]; //add more values

if ( cpf.length != 11 || possibleValues.indexOf( cpf ) != -1 )
{
  //value matching
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative *Ecmascript5* solution using `isNaN()` and `RegExp.text()` functions:

```
if (cpf.length !== 11 || (!isNaN(f = cpf[0]) && new RegExp("^"+ f + "{11}$").test(cpf))) {
    // do something
}
```

`isNaN()` - to check if we have only numbers(at start)

`new RegExp("^"+ f + "{11}$").test(cpf)` - to test if we have a sequence of same 11 digits